# Dont hide NSMenu after click

Tags: macos, cocoa

Have a way to I block hide the NSMenu after click.

Thanks.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you want to prevent the menu from closing? Doing this would conflict with a user's expectations of how a menu should behave. `cancelTracking` is definitely not what you want: *"Dismisses the menu and ends all menu tracking"* (from the NSMenu class documentation).

Answer (score 6):

No, I've written several menubar apps and I've found the only way to disable menu-closing is to subclass NSMenuItem and do your own event handling.  Unfortunately that also means you have to use a custom view, do your own title drawing, menu highlighting and "flash" animation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to switch to a view based menu item. Then in your view class, respond to `- (void) mouseUp:(NSEvent*) event` and implement your custom behavior. The menu will not close on the click, as the event is no longer forwarded up the responder chain to the menu item.